# Trouble accessing old Apple_HFS DVD

Tags: disk-utility, mount, dvd

I'm trying to read an old DVD that was burned in 1998.

I've tried mounting it through apple's own Disk utility app but it has shown `(com.apple.DiskManagement.disenter errore 49153).`

`Diskutil list` says that

```
/dev/disk3 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:        CD_partition_scheme                        *678.4 MB   disk3
   1:     Apple_partition_scheme                         590.7 MB   disk3s1
   2:        Apple_partition_map                         1.0 KB     disk3s1s1
   3:                  Apple_HFS Pasubio                 589.6 MB   disk3s1s2
```

I've tried mounting it through
`diskutil mount` but it tells

```
Volume on disk3 failed to mount
Perhaps the operation is not supported (kDAReturnUnsupported)
If it has a partitioning scheme, use "diskutil mountDisk"
If you think the volume is supported but damaged, try the "readOnly" option
```

None of the terminal suggestion worked.
I'm working from a MacBook pro Catalina mid 2012

Anybody can help?

UPDATE:
Thanks @jaume suggestion I've tried accessing to the disk installing `hfsprogs`  on Ubuntu VM and I succeeded into retrieving the raw files.
I leave the question open because I'd hope to access not only to the raw datas, (picture, sounds, ecc.) but also into the *app* version of the executable.

Thanks

Comment: What type of DVD is it exactly? Some DVD-Rs have an expected lifespan of only 5-10 years, others 10-20. 23 still might be pushing it.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. Have you tried reading the disc with another drive or another computer?

Comment: Hi @Tetsujin, thanks for the question.
On the top is written CD ROM Windows Macintosh.

Comment: Hi @jaume and thanks for the greetings.
I'm downloading Ubuntu on a Virtual machine because I don't own different laptops or places to try.
I've also read that Catalina won't read HFS.[link](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/251765370?answerId=253388361022#253388361022)

Comment: Ah, OK. I'm pretty sure when the link said use a VM it meant use an older macOS VM. Can Ubuntu read HFS? I would doubt it. I also doubt anything on the disk will work in Catalina either. It will all be 32-bit.